# An arithmetic sequence whose members do not contain the digit ‘9’

Tags: sequences-and-series, decimal-expansion

There is a non-constant arithmetic progression made of natural numbers only; none of them contains the digit $9$. Prove that such an arithmetic progression has no more than $72$ terms.

Comment: You should add some of your own thoughts on the matter, or you risk your question being closed. Can you write some of the basic properties of this series?

Comment: An example with length 72 is $1 + 125n$ for $n\in[0..71]$. The last 3 digits of the elements repeat with period 8, and happen not to contain any nines.  The leading digits increase at a rate of 1 per 8 elements, so don't reach 9 until the 72nd element.

Comment: But, this is only an example I can't prove it but d in the arithmetic series has a common divisor with 10,100,1000,10000....

Comment: I believe the repeat digit could help to the proof (period).

Comment: Can someone  post a clue or proof, please?

Comment: For first, if the step (i.e. the difference of two consecutive terms in the sequence) is $\equiv 1,3,7,9\pmod{10}$ the sequence cannot have more than $10$ terms since we fall soon into the residue class $9\pmod{10}$. We must also avoid to fall soon into the residue classes $90+[0,9]\pmod{100}$, hence the only choice is to have a step $\equiv 5\pmod{10}$, otherwise we have at most $44$ terms.

Comment: Now, if the step is $\equiv 5,15,35,75,95\pmod{100}$ we have at most $20$ terms. Hence we have that the step must be $\equiv 25,45,65,85\pmod{100}$.

Comment: If now we consider the subsequence given by the terms with an even index, we see that the only chance for the step is to be $\equiv 25\pmod{100}$, and we can finish by enumerating all the cases $100x+25\pmod{1000}$ in order to avoid the residue classes $900+[0,99]\pmod{1000}$, and check that we cannot have more than $72$ terms like in the $125m+1$ case.

Comment: But what about d=0 mod 10? 1+1250m still working.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio If you think you've completely proved the statement, it may be better to put it in the answers (as I think the comments are temporary & people may look at this thread for an answer in the future) :) .

Comment: @oliveeuler: I just added a proof. It is not very elegant since it is just a case-by-case sieving argument, but it is really simple to follow.

Answer (score 3):

We have a sequence $a_n = b+ns$, where we call $b$ the "base element" and $s$ the step. We notice for first that if $s\equiv 1,3,7,9\pmod{10}$ all the ten residue classes $\pmod{10}$ are covered by $a_0,\ldots,a_9$, hence the sequence cannot avoid the digit $9$ for more than $9$ terms. For a similar reason, we cannot have $s\equiv 2,4,6,8\pmod{10}$, since otherwise we fall into one of the residue classes $90+[0,9]\pmod{100}$ before the $45$th term. If $s\equiv 0\pmod{10}$, hence $s=10s'$, the digits represented by the sequence, apart from the last one that is constant, are the same that the digits represented by the sequence $a_n' = \lfloor b/10\rfloor + ns'$. So we may assume without loss of generality that $s\equiv 5\pmod{10}$. If now we focus on the sequence $b_n=a_{2n}$, we can easily deduce that $s\equiv 25\pmod{100}$ by the same way as above. By focusing now on $c_n = a_{4n}$, it is easy to check that, in order to avoid the residue classes $900+[0,99]\pmod{1000}$ in the first $40$ terms, the only chances are $s\equiv 125,625\pmod{1000}$. Now it is just tedious, by focusing on $d_n=a_{8n}$, to check that even such sequences cannot avoid the residue classes $9000+[0,999]\pmod{10^4}$ for more than $72$ terms, hence we're done.

Comment: why s=2,4,6,8 mod 10 why they fall to the 90+[0,9] and s=5 not?

Comment: I'm not exactly saying this. I'm saying that if $s\equiv 1,3,7,9\pmod{10}$ we have at most $9$ terms and at most $44$ terms if $s\equiv 2,4,6,8\pmod{10}$ (corresponding to half of the integers between $0$ and $90$). Since if $s\equiv 0\pmod{10}$ we can consider a reduced sequence by dropping the last constant digit, the only possible case to have more than $44$ terms is $s\equiv 5\pmod{10}$.

Comment: But when s=52 mod 100 the sequence isn't fall to 90,91,..,99.

Comment: Are you really sure? $52\cdot 21\equiv 92\pmod{100}$.

Comment: Now I understand what do you mean but how do you prove that s=2,4,6,8 mod 10 fall to 90+[0,9] mod 100?

Comment: Suppose that $s\pmod{10}\in\{2,4,6,8\}$ and consider the residue classes $\pmod{100}$ of the first few (say $50$) elements. Since the $gcd$ between $s$ and $100$ is at most $4$, at least $25$ different residue classes $\pmod{100}$ *in arithmetic progression* must be represented. Both in the case that $\gcd(s,100)=2$ and in the case that $\gcd(s,100)=4$, one of these residue classes must fall into the forbidden interval $90+[0,9]\pmod{100}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have thought I understand why s=2,4,6,8 mod 10 the sequence fall to residue classes 90+[0,9] but I understand why we have at least 25 different residue classes mod 100.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial solution. I thought I could extend it to a full solution, but that failed. The argument may be instructive, and could get somebody else on the track, so I will leave it here.

We cover the case where the arithmetic progression starts with 0,
so our sequence is $0,x,2x,\ldots$.
Assume that $x$ has $k$ decimal digits.
If we are counting in multiples of $x$ there is no way thay we can skip the
entire range from $[9\cdot 10^{k+1},10^{k+2})$, but if we want an arithmetic
progression of more then 10 terms avoiding 9, then we must clearly skip the
entire range $[9\cdot 10^k,10^{k+1})$.

This gives us the requirement that we need to find a one-digit number $b$
such that $bx\geq10^{k+1}$ and $(b-1)x<9\cdot 10^k$.

We will show that $b=9$ cannot work and that $b=8$ gives us exactly what we want.
Smaller values are not interesting: e.g. if $b=7$ this would imply that
$60x<90\cdot 10^k$ and $70x\geq 10^{k+2}$, so we get smaller limits.

When $b=9$ we get $9x\geq10^{k+1}$ and $8x<9\cdot 10^k$.

$9x\geq10^{k+1}$ implies $8x\geq\frac{80}{9}\cdot 10^k$,
so $\frac{80}{9}\cdot 10^k\leq 8x<9\cdot 10^k$.
This implies that already $8x$ contains a 9 (write down the decimal expansion of $\frac{80}{9}$ and realize that it is not an integer!), which is not what we are looking for.

When $b=8$ we get $8x\geq10^{k+1}$ and $7x<9\cdot 10^k$.

$8x\geq10^{k+1}$ implies that $x\geq\frac54\cdot 10^k$.
But then $72x\geq 90\cdot10^k$, so our sequence can have at most 72 terms
(note that we started with 0). The case $x=125$ shows that this result is sharp.